# Hibernate Hierarchical mapping good practice

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a hierarchical mapping problem. Conceptually 3 elements

1. Product Definition -- high level definition about a product . A product can be STANDARD or COMPOSITE . A standard product has a list of specifications. Where as, a composite product consists of list of 1 or more intermediate products . One product can be part of one or more COMPOSITE . Hence Product Definition may be optionally hierarchical with many-to-many association to itself. One Product (STANDARD) can be part of multiple COMPOSITE products and COMPOSITE products may have 1 or more child products.

[Constraints : I have to keep both type of products as same Entity class. Ultimately going to be published as web services. So a single definitions / schema is preferred.]

2. Product Specification -- Detailed specification about product
3. Product Composition -- if a product is constituted by 1 or more intermediate products, this maintains the relationship. Composition has some other attributes too.

---

```
class ProductDefinition {

   @ID
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="product_code")
   private String productCode;

   @Column(name="product_type")
   private String productType; // STANDARD, COMPOSITE

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="productDefinitionRef", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
   private Set<ProductSpec> productSpecs;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="childProductRef", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
   private Set<ProductComposition> compositionRefs; // For a standard product, lists the composites where the product belongs to

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentProductRef", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
   private Set<ProductComposition> childProducts;  // For a composite product, lists the proucts which are part of the composite



   // ... other attributes

}    

class ProductComposition {

   @ID
   private Long id;

   private ProductDefinition 

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="parent_prod_ref")
   private ProductDefinition parentProductRef;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="child_prod_ref")
   private ProductDefinition childProductRef;

   // ... Other attributes

}

class ProductSpec {

   @ID
   private Long id;


   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="prod_def_ref")
   private ProductDefinition productDefinitionRef;

   // .. other attributes


}
```

---

Some sample data which I am expecting from the above model :

Product Definition :-

```
| ID     |  Code  | Type |  productSpecs  | compositionRefs  |  childProducts |

| 1001 |    P1    | STANDARD  | [20001]     |   Empty       |   Empty |
| 1002 |    P2    | STANDARD  | [20002]     |   [2001]      |   Empty |
| 1003 |    P3    | STANDARD  | [20003]     |   [2001, 2002]|   Empty |
| 1004 |    P4    | STANDARD  | [20004]     |   Empty       |   Empty |
| 2001 |    B1    | COMPOSITE | Empty       |   Empty       | [1002]  |
| 2002 |    B2    | COMPOSITE | Empty       |   Empty       |   [1002, 1003] |
```

Product Composition :-

```
| ID    |   parentProductRef    |   childProductRef |
| 30005 |   2001    |   1002 |
| 30006 |   2002    |   1002 |
| 30007 |   2002    |   1003 |
```

Questions:-

1. Is this is an optimal way of mapping ? Please suggest if we can achieve anything better .
2. Is this way of referencing the same composition entity twice within the product entity supported ? I am hitting some inconsistency when I see the data in the DB but before I discuss that, I want to make sure that atleast in theory this is feasible.

Comment: So are you saying you couldn't consider using `@Inheritance` here and model your data more logically?  I would advocate doing this and if need be, leverage performing a data transformation in your rest service's controller or the service that your rest controller calls.

Comment: Yes, when I mentioned "constraints" I precisely meant that. Ideally Product should be a super class and each type i.e. Standard / Composite ( or others in future) should inherit Product. However any get API returning a Product will have some challenges describing the contract, specially in SOAP, where there is a schema associated. Each concrete type may result in a distinct schema type.

Comment: And there is the problem, @Rajesh.  You're allowing your exposed "view" of the data to dictate how to model the data.  You realize that is one of the worst mistakes developers make?  Model the data the way it makes sense in the database and then transform it in your rest/soap controller or service to whatever model your endpoint requires.  You'll thank me 1000 times over if you do!  By doing this, you can improve query performance because the data is modeled the right way for the database to handle joins appropriately and you take care of transformations in memory which is cheap.

Comment: @Naros , I'll review your suggestion and see how we can possibly work around the api issues which I mentioned.